# jquery function '.on("click")' starts uncalled

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, hide

I have a page with 2 images on it, if the user click on image A, function A starts and if the user click on image B, function B starts.
It looks something like this:

```
$('#imgA').on("click", function(){
    $('.challenge').hide('slow');
    alert('a');
});
$('#imgB').on("click", function(){
    $('.challenge').hide('slow');
    alert('b');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class='challenge' id='4'> 
    <img class='inline' id='imgA'> 
    <img class='inline' id='imgB'> 
</div>
```

I tested this code a couple of times and most of the times it works normal, but sometimes I click #imgA and first a get alert('a'), and right after I get alert('b') (or the other way around). In my program this is a serious bug.

Does anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<div class='challenge' id='4'>
  <img class='inline' id='imgA'>
  <img class='inline' id='imgB'>
</div>`
`

Comment: Put your code here: 
https://fiddle.jshell.net/ and send again please. Accept my edition.

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/#&togetherjs=8UJCHBu5H7

Comment: Unable to reproduce this error

Answer (score 2):

First of all change the method *one*  to ***on***.
According to your code you first have to close your  tags and add the event in each image you want to click:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="challenge">
    <div class='challenge' id='4'>

        <img style="cursor:pointer" id='a2' src='http://bit.ly/1B8xvUr' height='100px' width='200px'/>
        <img style="cursor:pointer" id='b4' src='http://bit.ly/1B8xvUr' height='100px' width='200px'/>

    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#a2').on("click", function () {
    alert('a');
    $(".challenge").hide('slow');
});
$('#b4').on("click", function () {
    alert('b');
    $(".challenge").hide('slow');
});
```

Also add style="cursor:pointer" in each image to see the pointer indicating it's clickable.

Take a look here:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/q9oa978j/3/

Comment: I changed method one to on and added the cursor style, yet, i still get the same mistake...?

Comment: Look at the fiddle. Did you close the img tags? Is the an img div above the other?

Comment: I closed the img tags, what do you mean with 'Is the an img div above the other'? Thanks for helping me so much!

Comment: Sorry I wrote wrong. I'd like to know if is there one div above the other. Realize that the code that I send you work fine, when you click in first div shows alert A, and when you click in second div shows alert B. What more do you need?